# Discord.js v12 Warn Command; Error with Math.floor

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have written a code to warn some users on a Discord server. Now Iáve got a problem with a Math.floor().
So this is my code:

```
...
const warns = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./database/fwarns.json', 'utf8'));
const totalpointsconfig = Math.floor(warns[striketo].warns + strikepoints);

if (warns[striketo]) {
                    warns[striketo] = {
                        warns: totalpointsconfig,
                    };
                }

fs.writeFile('./database/fwarns.json', JSON.stringify(warns), (err) => {
                    if (err) console.log(err);
                });

...
```

So the problem is that `const totalpointsconfig` doesn't work like I expect.

For example: `warns[striketo].warns` = 2, `strikepoints` = 2. So what i want is 2 +2 = `4`. But the output is `22`.
I'm not sure why it's doing that!

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with `Math.floor()`?

Comment: At least one of the variables (`warns[striketo].warns`, `strikepoints`) is a string

Comment: Yes, you're right! But i don't know how to fix that...

Comment: nvm fixed it. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the problem is that in Javascript, if you add two variables, from which at least one is a String and at most one is numeric, then it will yield a string result:

> 2 + "2" == "22"
>
> "2" + 2 == "22"
>
> "2" + "2" == "22"
>
> 2 + 2 = 4

So, you need to ensure that you have numbers. Assuming that you need integers:

```
const totalpointsconfig = Math.floor(parseInt(warns[striketo].warns) + parseInt(strikepoints));
```

EDIT

As Levi Op pointed out in the comment section, parseInt converts its input to integer.

Comment: For clarification, the `parseInt()` function takes a string and returns a number, fixing the problem

Comment: @Levi_OP thanks for the clarification. Edited my answer for better understandability.